# Jackson parsing and \ character issue

Tags: json, rest, jackson

I know that the question was a lot discussed, but for json data posted to a Spring RestController with a return to line, the character (\n) is generated:

**Here is my json:**

```
json = @"{""comment"":""" + comment + "\",\"sentFromReference\": \"" + fromRref + "\",\"chosenConductorNumber\": \"" + conductorNumber + "\",\"chosenVertJaune\": \"" + greenYellow + "\",\"chosenSection\": \"" + section + "\", \"projectId\":\""+projectId+"\" }";
```

In the comment attribute, id write a line, then begin a new line, wich translate to : "comment":"azpoeazpeou\nazejaozije"

the problem is with the \n

making an exception happen :

```
21-03-2016 11:49:51,693 [ervlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:377 :WARN ] http-bio-8080-exec-2 -  - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7bd6f635; line: 1, column: 41] (through reference chain: com.rexel.volta.dto.TransfertDto["comment"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
```

I actually don't want to escape the backslash caracter, i want it to be taken into account. How is this possible ? I am using Jackson version 1.9.13. Thank you for your help.